# ASPX page not loading in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, installation

I have a problem involving IIS. We installed our website in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. We created new Application Pool and Site Name. The path of the site is correct. But how come it doesn't load or it takes too long to load? Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough research, we found the problem last January or February I think. There were many disposable variables that is not disposed when we run code analysis in visual studio. So, we used using to dispose the variables that's causing the crashing not only from the web service but also from the applications that uses it.

```
e.g.
using(SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand())
{
  **code here**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the ASPX handler isn't properly registered with the server. Try running apsnet_regiis: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: we've already done that. we even uninstalled IIS in server roles. But still it takes too long to load and it doesn't display the login page.